# Problema con variable de sesión

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Quiero utilizar una variable de sesión para guardar el contenido de un DataSet. Ya lo había hecho comúnmente y sé que para usarlas no necesito declararlas y simplemente asignarle el valor, pero ahora que intento utilizarla de la siguiente manera:

Session["Dato"] = myDataSet;

Me da el error: "System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

System.Web.Services.WebService.Session.get devolvió null.
"

¿Hay alguna nueva forma de usar las variables de sesión?

P.D Mi dataset no está vacío.

Comment: Revisa que tu session no haya expirado, y porque necesitas guardar todo un dataset en session?

Comment: que tipo de desarrollo estas realizando? porque mencionas un web service y pones como tag a web api, pero no tiene que ves una cosa con otra. Hay proyectos donde la session debe habilitarse ya sea por codigo o configuracion para poder usarla, pero sin conocer que tipo de desarrollo realizas realmente no podria decirlo